# Does this Lucas-Kanade registration MATLAB script appear to be correct?

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

I'm currently writing a MATLAB script to replicate the Lucas-Kanade registration algorithm discussed here: [https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/lucas_bruce_d_1981_1.pdf](https://cecas.clemson.edu/%7Estb/klt/lucas_bruce_d_1981_1.pdf)

Specifically, I'm attempting to replicate the 2D implementation:

[image]

However, I'm struggling to get an output that accurately describes the translation I'm inducing.

First, I define two partial derivative functions "x_derivative" and "y_derivative" which simply take the difference of the input signal $f$.

Second, I use the derivative functions to calculate the X and Y partial derivatives.

Third, I input the matrices into the equation to calculate the X and Y components of the H vector. However, I appear to be getting "bad" results.

For example, I've been inputing a signal $g$ that is a 2 pixel right shift of $f$. However, I'm getting "bad" results. Ideally, I should be getting a vector H = [2, 0].

Any obvious mistakes I'm making?

```
function [h_x, h_y] = estimate(f, g)

% declare derivative function handles 
x_derivative = @(x)[diff(x, 1, 2), zeros(length(x(:, 1)), 1)]; % we append zero column such that output dimension = input dimension
y_derivative = @(x)[diff(x, 1, 1); zeros(1, length(x(1, :)))]; % we append row column such that output dimension = input dimension

f_derivative_x = x_derivative(f);
f_derivative_y = y_derivative(f);

% estimate x component
x_mat_numer = transpose(f_derivative_x) * (g - f);
x_sum_numer = sum(sum(x_mat_numer));

x_mat_denom = transpose(f_derivative_x) * f_derivative_x;
x_sum_denom = sum(sum(x_mat_denom));

h_x = x_sum_numer / x_sum_denom;

% estimate y component
y_mat_numer = transpose(f_derivative_y) * (g - f);
y_sum_numer = sum(sum(y_mat_numer));

y_mat_denom = transpose(f_derivative_y) * f_derivative_y;
y_sum_denom = sum(sum(y_mat_denom));

h_y = y_sum_numer / y_sum_denom;

end
```

Comment: It's years that I don't use matlab, but the implementation seems correct, but as it is pointed out in the paper is not a single pass procedure. Look at formula number 7-10. Therefore after the first call to this function you have to shift image f by the resulting vector h and compute again the estimation and so on until convergence. The basic idea is that you follow the gradient of the signal until you reach the zero difference between the images.